# Restore RDS Instance in Cluster from Snapshot with Different Class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I'm trying to create a dev instance of our aws rds db with a nightly script. Our db is an rds cluster with a main instance (main-db) and a read replica instance (main-db-rr).

I have a script that works using the aws-cli, but I seem to have hit a limitation of Amazons cli. I dont want to use restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot since that would create a read replica dev instance that I dont need.

More importantly that command doesn't let me modify the class of the new rds instance like the restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot does with --db-instance-class argument.

I thought about taking a snapshot of main-db only and not main-db-rr, and restoring that with the command above using the --db-instance-class argument, but the create-db-snapshot command doesnt allow me to snapshot an instance part of a cluster, even though I can do it in the AWS Web Console.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can create a scaled down version of my production db instance, from a snapshot?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're talking about an Aurora cluster, right?  What specifically happens when you try to `create-db-snapshot` of a singe instance using aws-cli?

Comment: Yes this is an Aurora cluster. When I call create-db-snapshot on a single instance, the aws-cli spits back this error `An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateDBSnapshot operation: The specified instance is a member of a cluster and a snapshot cannot be created directly. Please use the CreateDBClusterSnapshot API instead`

Comment: The console and the cli communicate with the underlying service using the same [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), so it's *usually* the case that anything you can do with the console can be done with the cli.  I'll have to investigate, before I can say more, since I am only currently using Aurora for non-critical services and so don't have any multi-member clusters running at the moment.  You might be able to figure out what the console is doing by reverse-engineering its behavior with [AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/).